# Using a variable in a Global context in webapps

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, web-applications

In a webapp, I have a scenario where I need some kind of global context (Static like) for few variables, *for the current thread only*.

If there are 3 different concurrent users, then I expect three corresponding global context variable for the 3 separate threads/sessions.

Using a Static variable makes its scope global for all the threads.

Is there a way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: How about using session scope? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html

Comment: The issue here is that the web fundamentally does not work like that. The correct solution is session variables, but you have to understand that there is no thread here. Three users requesting multiple pages don't necessarily have a thread "each". If user two goes away for an hour, then comes back, you won't keep a thread idle for them. If you have 20,000 concurrent users you won't hold open 20,000 threads. Indeed, nginx, a webserver widely considered by many to be about the fastest available does not thread at all (though it does suffer for that when serving dynamic content)

Comment: @Phoshi I agree with you, and I regret the way I phrased my question. However, the question is about these individual `requests`. Thanks for the correction and insight!

Comment: @Rakesh: You're looking for "session" variables, then. In Java access to that is implemented as the session scope, similarly to the request scope.

Comment: `ThreadLocal`, pretty basic construct in Java, explained in tutorials for beginners

Comment: Or even keep some "user context" in a database!

Answer (score 2):

A `ThreadLocal` is what you want. However, in your situation, I think that you should go for `Session` scoped variables.